# "The gdb process crashed"

Tags: qt, gdb

When I run this minimal program in Qt Creator, I'm served with the error "The gdb process crashed":

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the `gdb` log:

```
ADAPTER SUCCESSFULLY STARTED
NOTE: ENGINE SETUP OK
State changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupOk(3).
QUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
State changed from EngineSetupOk(3) to InferiorSetupRequested(4).
QUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
HANDLE GDB ERROR: The gdb process was ended forcefully
GDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 1, code -1073741701
NOTE: ENGINE ILL ******
State changed from InferiorSetupRequested(4) to EngineShutdownRequested(20).
QUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
CALL: SETUP INFERIOR
Setting up inferior...
CALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
PLAIN ADAPTER SHUTDOWN 20
INITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN IN STATE 4, PROC: 0
NOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN OK
State changed from EngineShutdownRequested(20) to EngineShutdownOk(22).
State changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23).
QUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
NOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
HANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
Debugger finished.
```

I'm using gdb 6.8 in the *i686-pc-mingw32* configuration. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by an incompatible version of `python27.dll` in `QtSDK\pythongdb\python_2.7based`. I had replaced it because Secunia PSI kept nagging me that this DLL was outdated and insecure. I reverted to the old DLL and it works fine now.